# please explain why this c# extension method works

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I bought  pro asp.net mvc2 framework book. I got stuck on page 122.  I couldn't understand why it works.

I already emailed author, didnt get anything back yet. here's the code, can someone please explain to me why it works.

```
    public static class PagingHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html, PagingInfo pagingInfo, Func<int, string> pageUrl)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 1; i <= pagingInfo.TotalPages; i++)
        {
            TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
            tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i));

            tag.InnerHtml = i.ToString();

            if (i == pagingInfo.CurrentPage)
                tag.AddCssClass("selected");

            result.AppendLine(tag.ToString());
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
    }
}
```

this PageLinks helper method needs 3 parameters, but later in the book, when author call it,

```
<%: Html.PageLinks(
      new PagingInfo { CurrentPage = 2, TotalItems = 28, ItemsPerPage = 10 },
      i => Url.Action("List", new{ page = i})
) %>
```

author only passed in 2 parameters,  HtmlHelper html is missing, but it sitll works.  I couldn't figure out why, please help, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first parameter to an extension method is the object it's called on.  (`Html` in your example).

You can read [more about extension methods on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Extension methods differ from other methods in that they are

- Declared static
- The first parameter is the object on which it is called
- The first parameter is prefixed by the this keyword

Further discussion can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Since the first parameter is defined as <**this** Type name> as opposed to the usual  the compiler knows to build it in such a way that the first parameter is automatically handled for you, and thus you only need to worry about those params if any that follow.